# Overflow Text with Scroll but overflow html element out of it

Tags: html, css, scroll, tooltip, overflow

my english is not the best but i hope to write the question 
understandable.

I´m trying to make a div text editable, normally the text will overflow the size of the div so i need to keep the text in the div with `overflow:scroll` but i want to acept html elements in that div, especially a tooltip. And this html-element (the tooltip) normally go out of the div but if i use `overflow:scroll` to manage the text i lose the property to let the tooltip overflow. Here is an image that ilustrate what happen:

[image]

There is the codepen with the code whate the image show:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwXGRE?editors=1100

```css
#Out {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#noOut {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

body {
  background: red;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* Use half of the width (120/2 = 60), to center the tooltip */
}
```

```html
<div id="Out" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1
  div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1</div>

<div id="noOut" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></div>div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2
    div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2</div>`
```

In conclusion i need to let the tooltip overflow but not the text.

Again sorry for my bad english, and i´ll appreciate any tip or kind of help :).

Comment: you have not specified height for your tooltip

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your problem? I couldn't understand.

Comment: Oh sorry, it could be dynamic. For example in a range of 20px-900px. But not necessary is in that range.

Comment: I need to make a contenteditable div what allows to show the tooltip(html-element) outside of the div but dont let the (non-html)-elements overflow (like normal text). In the snippet you can hover the second box(div) and see the tooltip but the text is out of the div (i need the text not overflowing) and if you hover the first box(div) you can´t see the tooltip but te text is not overflowing. Is like the normal text need :"overflow:scroll" and the html elements "overflow:initial". But the overflow property is with the <div id="out"> and can"t have both propertys at the same time

Comment: overflow else than visble will hide anything outside it. To show that tooltip and still use overflow, the tooltip has to be taken out. it can be a sibbling or eventually a pseudo element of the div

Comment: In tooltip why have you put hover over me and a span?

Comment: Yes GCyrillus  i´m in agree with you, but for example i want to show the tooltip just above of the  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me</div>, and it can be in any place of the contenEditable div. If i use pseudo element of the div like ::before i"ll lose that relative position, i can do a "hacky" method with javascript.But i like to ask if exist another more efficient way to achieve it. I hope i understand your answer GCyrillus if not, correct me please :)

Comment: the (hover over me) is the "trigger Element" when you hover the mouse in it the tooltip appear. The span is the tooltip element itself. RobertWilliams

Comment: If you want the tooltip appear when you hover the div Out then there is no need to apply tooltip class on the whole text. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** 
Here is your solution:

```css
body {
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.outContainer {
  position: relative;
}

#Out {
  background: #333;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hover-div {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  color: #333;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-div:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outContainer">
  <div id="Out" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="hover-div">1- Hover Over here
      <div class="tooltip">Tooltip text</div>
    </div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    <div class="hover-div">2- Hover Over again
      <div class="tooltip">Tooltip text</div>
    </div>
    Additional text goes here It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
  </div>
</div>
```

Code pen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/KqbQoO?editors=1100

Comment: Let me study your answer because with a little changes of your code we near achieve the final result (and is my fault because i don´t put all the details) in this codepen is the changes : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZvJeY

The last what i need is show that tooltip just above of the <div>hover me</div> element. Where ever is it. i Think your answer is correctly for the question. But let me investigate more how to achieve that final detail (putting the tooltip just above the hover element). So you deserve the correct answer but i still want to achieve the last thing. let me keep working on it

Comment: I´ll study too the Gerard Answer, i insist, you deserve the correct answer value but maybe is a lame to open another question just for that last detail. Is better for the comunnity organization if i open a new question ?

Comment: No there is no need to open a new question. Tell me the whole issue again what is the problem. I will help you achieve your goal :)

Comment: Let me explain to you, if I am wrong correct me. You want  a div which is editable and scroll-able, then in that div at different points you will add headings or something else (additional divs) and when a user hover over that small div a tooltip should appear over the main editable and scroll-able div. Am I right?

Comment: That is exactly what i need!. You read my mind haha (because my explanation was very bad :( haha )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148975/discussion-between-robert-williams-and-user3657540).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the positioning of `.tooltiptext`. In the first example, the parent which has relative positioning, is closed after the `span`. In the second example there is a closing `div` missing. When I add it to the end and change the position of the tooltip, it works fine.

```css
#Out {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#noOut {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

body {
  background: red;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  top: -2em;
  /* Use half of the width (120/2 = 60), to center the tooltip */
}
```

```html
<div id="Out" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1
  div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1 div1</div>

<div id="noOut" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2
    div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2 div2</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr.Gerard. Yes i missing de closing div.That was one problem of my codification but no is the problem of the main question. In the first Example i want the tooltip appear but i can"t because i have a overflow:scroll  . In the second example the tooltip appear but the text go out of the div so i want achieve this combination: Tooltip:Can overflow(any html element)  NormalText:Can´T overflow

Answer (score 0):

You need something extra.

This is one of those things where CSS hasn't quite *caught on*.

Nevertheless, it's still possible with pure CSS.

So you **want the tool tip to appear** but also **don't want the div to overflow horizontally**. You also **don't want to affect any other elements**.

You can mess around with **hard-coded CSS positioning** but that will not be easy to work with if you need to implement your idea on many elements.

The fix comes in the form of [Hint.css](https://github.com/chinchang/hint.css):

> A CSS only tooltip library for your lovely websites

I believe this library will assist in getting the desired effect but not entirely as you described.

Here's a working example of how I would display a tooltip for the element you described while keeping things clean and simple.

The tool tip **will always be displayed at the bottom of the screen** no matter what. It will never affect anything else.

```css
[class*="hint--"]:after {
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 200px;
  transform: none !important;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, darkred 30%, #131418)!important;
  border-radius: 100vw 100vw 0 0;
}

#Out {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#Out>span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hint.css/2.4.0/hint.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="Out">
  <span contenteditable="true" class="hint--" aria-label="Tool tip text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit no mentitum eleifend. Rebum detracto intellegebat vel ei, pro ne erroribus quaerendum. Malorum nonumes id cum, mei case meliore ut, et enim platonem nec. Eu est option qualisque efficiantur, te errem mucius dolorum nec, putent quaerendum et sea. Ex stet dignissim democritum sed, has te putant ceteros blandit.

Adhuc sanctus intellegat no his, falli viris ei mei, id eum tritani virtute. Iudico audire urbanitas at est, graece antiopam constituam mei eu. Vero animal salutatus nam ea. Essent intellegam cu sea, per legendos suavitate an. Duo sale omittantur definitionem ea, affert quaeque deseruisse ea pro. Vix errem intellegam scripserit eu, sit ex suscipiantur mediocritatem conclusionemque, sonet insolens ex nec.

Velit delenit pri in, ne his nemore torquatos. Ex postea fabulas signiferumque vix, consul postea mea cu, an choro verterem sea. Quod assum vis et. An nam affert quidam. Duo tation patrioque in, ut ludus nihil vel.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer whose link I shared in chat.

```css
body {
  background: pink;
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#Out {
  background: #333;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hover-div {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  color: #333;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hover-div:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outContainer">
  <div id="Out" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="hover-div">Hover over me
      <div class="tooltip">Tooltip text</div>
    </div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    <div class="hover-div">Hover over me
      <div class="tooltip">Tooltip text</div>
    </div>
    Additional text goes here It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Adjust position of tooltip by playing with left, right, top as per your needs.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/KqbQoO?editors=1100